# Login issue with ftplib but not with Paramiko?

Tags: python, ftp, sftp, paramiko, ftplib

I am trying to connect with a host with [ftplib](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ftplib.html) but every time it says-

```
File "E:\NTUC\virtualenv\lib\ftplib.py", line 152, in connect
source_address=self.source_address)
File "E:\NTUC\virtualenv\lib\socket.py", line 724, in create_connection
raise err
File "E:\NTUC\virtualenv\lib\socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because 
the target machine actively refused it
```

But with the same credentials if I use [Paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/), it connects me successfully.

My ftplib code:

```
import ftplib
f = ftplib.FTP()
f.connect("HOST")
f.login("USER_NAME", "PASSWORD")
ls = []
f.retrlines('MLSD', ls.append)
for entry in ls:
    print(entry)
```

My Paramiko code:

```
import paramiko
transport = paramiko.Transport((HOST, PORT))
transport.connect(username=USER_NAME, password=PASSWORD)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paramiko is SSH/SFTP library. ftplib is FTP library. These protocols are completely different.

The fact that you can connect with Paramiko actually means that you definitely cannot connect to the same host+port using ftplib. And you quite likely cannot connect to the host at all using ftplib, even if you try an FTP port (what you seem to try), as servers usually offer FTP *or* SFTP, but not *both*.

In any case, a successful connection with SFTP (Paramiko) says nothing at all about FTP (ftplib).